# Should an ORACLE-SPATIAL tag be created?

Tags: discussion, tag-creation

DBA SE has an `ORACLE` tag and a `SPATIAL` tag, but it doesn't have an `ORACLE-SPATIAL` tag.

Sites that that presently have an `ORACLE-SPATIAL` tag are:

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-spatial)
- [GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-spatial)

I think it would be helpful to have a tag that pertains specifically to the [Oracle Spatial product](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database-options/spatialandgraph/overview/spatialandgraph-1707409.html). It would allow people to differentiate between topics/datatypes that are `ORACLE` and `SPATIAL` in nature, but not `ORACLE-SPATIAL` (example: a [user-defined datatype](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/what-is-the-st-geometry-storage-type.htm) or  manual spatial calculations that do not use Oracle Spatial) versus topics/datatypes that are strictly related to `ORACLE-SPATIAL` (and it's SDO_Geometry data-type, packages, functions, etc.).

Should an `ORACLE-SPATIAL` tag be created on DBA SE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No

Compound tags should be discouraged. The only thing a compound tag does is waste a slot better suited for something that adds a descriptive quality. Tags aren't categories. They should be atomic. That's why you can search for `[spatial] [oracle`]